# Sum of Neighborhoods of Zero

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, elementary-set-theory, vector-spaces, topological-vector-spaces

When do two neighborhoods of zero over a topological vector space add up as:
$$aN+bN=(a+b)N\quad a,b\geq 0$$
I could imagine something like balanced might suffice...

The problem is that I'd like to estimate:
$$N|\mu(A_1)|+\ldots+N|\mu(A_N)|=N(|\mu(A_1)|+\ldots+|\mu(A_N)|)$$

Comment: Note that the equation $N+(-1)N=0N$ is nonsense. Indeed, if $N$ is balanced, then $N+(-1)N = N + N = 2N$.

Comment: I added the vector space tag, as this question seems to be more about vector spaces than topology.

Comment: I made an edit to my answer corresponding to the added part of your question.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta: Yep saw it ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation $aN+bN=(a+b)N$ is true for any convex set $N$ in a real vector space when $a$ and $b$ have the same sign.
Clearly $aN+bN\supset(a+b)N$, so only the other direction needs to be shown.

Take $x\in aN+bN$.
Then there are $y,z\in N$ so that $x=ay+bz=(a+b)\left(\frac{a}{a+b}y+\frac{b}{a+b}z\right)$.
By convexity $\frac{a}{a+b}y+\frac{b}{a+b}z\in N$, so $x\in(a+b)N$.
Thus $aN+bN\subset(a+b)N$.

**Remarks**:

- The location of $N$ is irrelevant.
  If you replace $N$ with $c+N$, the equation $aN+bN=(a+b)N$ is unchanged.
- If $N$ is balanced and convex, then the previous proof shows that $aN+bN=(|a|+|b|)N$.
  If $a$ and $b$ have different sign and $N$ is not the whole space, then $aN+bN\neq(a+b)N$.
  (Thus for bounded, balanced, convex sets (containing more than one point) OP's property holds if and only if $a$ and $b$ have the same sign.)
- Topology plays no role. This seems to be all about the vector space structure.

**Edit:**
The OP added to the question that they want to have the estimate
$$
N|\mu(A_1)|+\ldots+N|\mu(A_N)|=N(|\mu(A_1)|+\ldots+|\mu(A_N)|)\subseteq N|\mu|(A_1\cup\ldots\cup A_N),
$$
where $N$ is presumably balanced and convex.
Since the numbers $|\mu(A_i)|$ are all positive and thus have the same sign, the equality part is true.
The inclusion is equivalent with
$$
|\mu(A_1)|+\ldots+|\mu(A_N)|
\leq
|\mu|(A_1\cup\ldots\cup A_N).
$$
Establishing this requires more assumptions and it is false as stated (assuming $\mu$ is a measure, signed or not).
If $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure on the real axis (now $\mu=|\mu|$) and $A_i=[i,3i]$, then $|\mu(A_1)|+|\mu(A_2)|=6>5\mu(A_1\cup A_2)$.

If the sets $A_i$ are disjoint and measurable (and $\mu$ is a signed measure), then
$$
|\mu(A_1)|+\ldots+|\mu(A_N)|
\leq
|\mu|(A_1)+\ldots+|\mu|(A_N)
=
|\mu|(A_1\cup\ldots\cup A_N),
$$
and the desired estimate is true.

Comment: First of all thanks to the great answer :) Does the equality also hold for merely balanced neighborhoods of zero?

Comment: By the way I missed to note that all the subsets are disjoint measurable sets - but your last statement why should it fail in general (note I'm taking the total variation measure)?

Comment: You're welcome. :) Balanced is not enough. If $N=(-10,10)\times(-1,1)\cup(-1,1)\times(-10,10)\subset\mathbb R^2$ and $a=b=1$, then $(10,10)\in (aN+bN)\setminus(a+b)N$.

Comment: You are right, if the sets are disjoint, the inequality is true. I'll edit.

Comment: Right - do I also have to care about it being *complex* rather than real vector space?

Comment: No, since a complex vector space is also a real vector space and being complex balanced ($zN\subset N$ whenever $|z|\leq1$) implies being real balanced.